# "dissecting" an R calculation (Show results calculated in C)

Tags: c, r

Is it possible to track each calculation `R` is going through to get the final result?

Consider `qnorm()`. Is it possible to return the values for `q`, `p_`, `val` and `r` in some way? Maybe with a hack?

```
double qnorm5(double p, double mu, double sigma, int lower_tail, int log_p)
{
    double p_, q, r, val;

#ifdef IEEE_754
    if (ISNAN(p) || ISNAN(mu) || ISNAN(sigma))
return p + mu + sigma;
#endif
    R_Q_P01_boundaries(p, ML_NEGINF, ML_POSINF);

    if(sigma < 0)   ML_ERR_return_NAN;
    if(sigma == 0)  return mu;

    p_ = R_DT_qIv(p);/* real lower_tail prob. p */
    q = p_ - 0.5;

#ifdef DEBUG_qnorm
    REprintf("qnorm(p=%10.7g, m=%g, s=%g, l.t.= %d, log= %d): q = %g\n",
p,mu,sigma, lower_tail, log_p, q);
#endif


/*-- use AS 241 --- */
/* double ppnd16_(double *p, long *ifault)*/
/* ALGORITHM AS241 APPL. STATIST. (1988) VOL. 37, NO. 3

Produces the normal deviate Z corresponding to a given lower
tail area of P; Z is accurate to about 1 part in 10**16.

(original fortran code used PARAMETER(..) for the coefficients
and provided hash codes for checking them...)
*/
    if (fabs(q) <= .425) {/* 0.075 <= p <= 0.925 */
        r = .180625 - q * q;
val =
            q * (((((((r * 2509.0809287301226727 +
                       33430.575583588128105) * r + 67265.770927008700853) * r +
                     45921.953931549871457) * r + 13731.693765509461125) * r +
                   1971.5909503065514427) * r + 133.14166789178437745) * r +
                 3.387132872796366608)
            / (((((((r * 5226.495278852854561 +
                     28729.085735721942674) * r + 39307.89580009271061) * r +
                   21213.794301586595867) * r + 5394.1960214247511077) * r +
                 687.1870074920579083) * r + 42.313330701600911252) * r + 1.);
    }
    else { /* closer than 0.075 from {0,1} boundary */

/* r = min(p, 1-p) < 0.075 */
if (q > 0)
r = R_DT_CIv(p);/* 1-p */
else
r = p_;/* = R_DT_Iv(p) ^= p */

r = sqrt(- ((log_p &&
((lower_tail && q <= 0) || (!lower_tail && q > 0))) ?
p : /* else */ log(r)));
        /* r = sqrt(-log(r)) <==> min(p, 1-p) = exp( - r^2 ) */
#ifdef DEBUG_qnorm
REprintf("\t close to 0 or 1: r = %7g\n", r);
#endif

        if (r <= 5.) { /* <==> min(p,1-p) >= exp(-25) ~= 1.3888e-11 */
            r += -1.6;
            val = (((((((r * 7.7454501427834140764e-4 +
                       .0227238449892691845833) * r + .24178072517745061177) *
                     r + 1.27045825245236838258) * r +
                    3.64784832476320460504) * r + 5.7694972214606914055) *
                  r + 4.6303378461565452959) * r +
                 1.42343711074968357734)
                / (((((((r *
                         1.05075007164441684324e-9 + 5.475938084995344946e-4) *
                        r + .0151986665636164571966) * r +
                       .14810397642748007459) * r + .68976733498510000455) *
                     r + 1.6763848301838038494) * r +
                    2.05319162663775882187) * r + 1.);
        }
        else { /* very close to 0 or 1 */
            r += -5.;
            val = (((((((r * 2.01033439929228813265e-7 +
                       2.71155556874348757815e-5) * r +
                      .0012426609473880784386) * r + .026532189526576123093) *
                    r + .29656057182850489123) * r +
                   1.7848265399172913358) * r + 5.4637849111641143699) *
                 r + 6.6579046435011037772)
                / (((((((r *
                         2.04426310338993978564e-15 + 1.4215117583164458887e-7)*
                        r + 1.8463183175100546818e-5) * r +
                       7.868691311456132591e-4) * r + .0148753612908506148525)
                     * r + .13692988092273580531) * r +
                    .59983220655588793769) * r + 1.);
        }

if(q < 0.0)
val = -val;
        /* return (q >= 0.)? r : -r ;*/
    }
    return mu + sigma * val;
}
```

Comment: You tagged this with wrong language tag. This is not R syntax

Comment: If you do not need to return those values, you could just `Rprintf` them?

Comment: Thank you. Changed tag to be more appropriate.

Comment: In your title and first sentence you still refer to `R`.  If `R` is using a `C++` function I suggest using both the `R` and `C++` tags since your question is relevant to both languages.

Comment: My guess here is that you know very little about software, so: the difficulty is that any `c++` code is compiled, which means if you want to change the outputs you'll have to edit the source code (quoted in your question) and recompile.  The alternative is to port the equations into `R` or other high-level language and change the returned values.  That approach will lead to slower execution times.